# Close Navigation Drawer on back pressed

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a material designed navigation drawer created following [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/).

When back button is pressed, the app quit. What I want to do is to close the navigation drawer on back pressed. This is the original code:

```
drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
```

I added this:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        if (this.drawerFragment.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            this.drawerFragment.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

However, I got error cannot resolve method `isDrawerOpen` and `closeDrawer`.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you shouldn't be using the fragment to open and close the drawer. instead try using the drawer layout.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout layout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```